# What is the suitable Graph Machine Learning model for dynamic graph forecasting with changing nodes and edges features

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, graphical-model, graph-theory

I have a graph where each node carries a feature value(s). The edges in the graph are weighted and each edge carries a single value (weight). The weight of the edge is some value calculated using the feature values of the connected nodes (some normalized difference).  The graph is dynamic in the sense that the node feature value(s) changes over time, and hence the weight of the edges. I would like to forecast the graph. In other words, I would like to forecast these nodes and edges values that change over time. I have the history values (the time series).

Is graph machine learning helpful here to solve this time-series forecasting problem? If so, what is the best model?

I have done some research, and found [An Application of Spatio-Temporal Graph Neural Networks to Traffic Prediction](https://medium.com/stanford-cs224w/predicting-evolution-of-dynamic-graphs-7688eca1daf8). My concern is that the application itself could be different and hence this may affect the choice of the model/algorithm.